# php code being displayed in browser

Tags: php, mysql, web, webserver, xampp

I have written php script for user login but instead of displaying the result the whole script is being displayed.I have given a .php file link as an action for the login form.

I am using xampp with php and mysql running do I need anything else?

### the code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame 
       Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <title>Ch</title>
  <meta name="description" content="education,India,College search in india,score evaluator" />
  <meta name="author" content="RAJATEJAS" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />

  <style type = "text/css">
    user_login , input
    {
        display = inline;   
    }   
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>Ch</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <p><a href="/">Home</a></p>
      <p><a href="/contact">Contact</a></p>
    </nav>

    <div class = "user_login_form">
        <form action = "chalo_login.php" method="post">
            <label>Username:</label><input id = "username" type = "text" name = "username" autofocus placeholder="Enter Username"/><br />
            <label>Password:</label><input id = "password" type = "password" name = "password" placeholder="Enter Password"/><br />
            <input name = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Login" />
        </form>   
    </div>


    <footer>
     <p>&copy; Copyright  by RAJATEJAS</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_POST['username'];
    $_POST['password'];

    if ($username&&$password)
    {
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die("could not find database");
        $query = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "$username");
        $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows !=0)
        {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $dbusername = $row["username"];
                $dbpassword = $row["password"];
            }
            if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
            {
                echo "You are logged in! ;
                <a href ="member.php">Click here</a>";
                $_SESSION["username"] = $dbusername;

            }
            else
            {
                echo "Incorrect password";
            }
        }else{die("Account does not exists");}
    } 
    else 
    {
    die ("Please enter details");   
    }

?>
```

Comment: is your webserver running? or you just double clicked on the file? You need to put your files in the correct location

Comment: you have an error in your syntax at your echo "you are loggged in" statement. you are using the quotes improperly

Comment: if even the `<?php` tag got printed, then the file isn't interpreted by the php interpreter via webserver. you might be just opening local file. just check your browser's address bar, it should start with http:// instead of file://.

Comment: the debugger says some error with the "users" i have rectified the " error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few errors in your code, but I don't know if they're what are causing your problems.

Firstly in your CSS `user_login` should be `#user_login` to select elements with the ID "user_login". Then, `display = inline;` should be `display: inline;`.

In your PHP...

```
$_POST['username'];
$_POST['password'];
```

...doesn't do anything. I think you should have

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

And as Ethan mentioned in the comments above, your quotation marks are messed up:

```
echo "You are logged in! ;
<a href ="member.php">Click here</a>";
```

...should probably be:

```
echo "You are logged in! <a href =\"member.php\">Click here</a>";
```

(Escape your quotation marks inside quotation marks using a backslash).

Fix those errors and see if it works then...

Also: as LeleDumbo says above, make sure the page is being loaded through Apache rather than opened as a file. The URL should begin with something like `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. If not, just put `127.0.0.1` into your address bar and browse to your file in the list that appears.

---

Another error- your `SELECT` statement needs to be a string:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Comment: i tried run through apache but it does not recognize "users" even though I have users in phpmyadmin database as both a database name and a table name

Comment: I've added another error regarding your MySQL query to my answer. Also, you say that your database and table are both called "users", but in your code you are opening a database called "phplogin".

Comment: @user1 Then sort out your database code. Check you're logging into the correct database, have access to the tables and that the `users` table actually exists. Please put some of your own effort into this; the solution to your original question doesn't take much Googling to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Variables $username and $password are not assigned

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])
{
$username=$_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['password'])
{
$password=$_POST['password'];
}
```

and the select the correct database in the comment above you are saying that your database name is also "users" but you have selected "phplogin"